# I want jquery code where I can compare on a parallax page whether a particular div's scrolltop is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I want jquery code where I can compare on a parallax page whether a particular div's `scrolltop` is 0

```
 $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
        $('#home').css({position: 'relative'});
        $('.home').removeClass('active');
     }
     else {
            $('#home').css({position: 'fixed'});
     }
});
```

How can I modify this code to compare the div is particular div suppose

div id='slide5'.

Is on top

Comment: Change `$(window)` to `$('#slide5')`. I would suggest you read the selectors page of http://api.jquery.com as this is the simplest task in jQuery.

Comment: $(window).scroll(function() {
 var styledDiv = $('#divtochange'),
    targetScroll = $('#divtocompare').position().top,
    currentScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
 styledDiv.toggleClass('makehide', currentScroll >= targetScroll);
 });


How do i add time delay into it

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<div id="id1">Semple page 1<div>
 <div id="id2">Semple page 2<div>
 <div id="id3">Semple page 3<div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#id1").bind('scroll', function (event) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {

    //Your operation 

    }
    });



$("#id2").bind('scroll', function (event) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {

    //Your operation 

    }
    });



$("#id3").bind('scroll', function (event) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {

    //Your operation 

    }
    });
```

Comment: $(window).scroll(function() {
 var styledDiv = $('#divtochange'),
    targetScroll = $('#divtocompare').position().top,
    currentScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
 styledDiv.toggleClass('makehide', currentScroll >= targetScroll);
 });


How do i add time delay into it

Comment: add timer after your condition is matched.